# Rails simple to_param not working on one of my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Product and no matter what I do I can not get to_params to work. The url is always website_name/shop/product.id. Thanks in advance.

Here is my product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'STOCK'
  self.primary_key = 'NUMBER'

  def to_param
    "#{NUMBER} #{DESC1}".parameterize
  end

  has_one :product_override, foreign_key: 'sku'
end
```

Here is my Shop Controller index action:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    #params[:category] ||= 'CAMERAS'
    #q = params[:category]
    @featured = Product.joins(:product_override).where("product_overrides.featured = ? and product_overrides.active = ?",1,1).where("DISCONT = ? and NONPRODUCT = ?" ,0,0).limit(18)
end

end
```

Here is the link in my view:

```
<%= link_to product.NUMBER, shop_path(product.id) %>
```

Comment: can you show the schema of your `products` table?

Comment: `self.table_name = 'STOCK'` means you are mapping your `Product` class to `STOCK` table in the database. Why are you doing so? Also, table name should be like `stocks` NOT `STOCK` Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I am  using a legacy database that is integrated with our inventory system. The STOCK table is what should be the products table. I can not change that so mapped it that way.

Comment: So, how it looks like in the database? `stocks`?

Comment: No the table name is STOCK

Comment: can you show the table's columns?

Comment: The only column I am referring to is the NUMBER and UNITS columns. The would normally be id and qty

Comment: `"#{NUMBER} #{DESC1}"` from where these two are coming from?

Comment: They both come from the STOCK table

Comment: NUMBER is the id field in the STOCK table

Comment: Inside your `to_param` method can you try: `puts #{NUMBER.inspect}` and `puts #{DESC1.inspect}` before `"#{NUMBER} #{DESC1}".parameterize `to see what's in there when the request is made. I suspect it's not getting the value. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87720/discussion-between-drd-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Comment: is this correct ? def to_param
    puts #{NUMBER.inspect}
    puts #{DESC1.inspect}
    "#{NUMBER} #{DESC1}".parameterize
  end

Answer (score 0):

The path you generate for your link is explicitly getting `product.id`, so Rails has no chance to use your custom `to_param` method. Use just `product` instead so the helper has access to your object.

```
<%= link_to product.NUMBER, shop_path(product) %>
```